# Retrying connection with Play's AhcWSClient

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Play's `AhcWSClient` to make HTTP requests (I'm not using the rest of the Play framework):

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
val wsClient = AhcWSClient()
wsClient
  .url(s"http://somerandomurl.com/somethingsomething")
  .get()
  .map { wsResponse =>
    if (!(200 to 299).contains(wsResponse.status)) {
      sys.error(s"Received unexpected status ${wsResponse.status} : ${wsResponse.body}")
    }
    println(s"OK, received ${wsResponse.body}")
  }(system.dispatcher)
}
```

**How can I instruct the WSClient to retry the request if it fails?**

Looking at the docs, it [seems to be possible](http://www.lookatsrc.com/source/play/api/libs/ws/ahc/AhcConfig.scala?a=com.typesafe.play:play-ws_2.11) to use an `AsyncHttpClientConfig` using a `maxNumberOfRedirects` parameter (which refers to "The maximum number of times to retry a request if it fails") but how?

**Update:** So, apparently, when creating a `AhcWSClient` we get [five retries by default](http://www.lookatsrc.com/source/play/api/libs/ws/ahc/AhcConfig.scala?a=com.typesafe.play:play-ws_2.11), and can specify our own `AhcWSClientConfig` with a different `maxRequestRetry`. But when I issue requests that return a 502 status code I don't see the multiple attempts happening... What should I expect to count as a "failed request"?

Answer (score 0):

Usually clients should only retry methods which are [idempotent](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> The methods GET, HEAD, PUT and DELETE share this property. Also, the methods OPTIONS and TRACE SHOULD NOT have side effects, and so are inherently idempotent.